# router.get('/page') express Router not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, netlify

I am trying to make a simple express routing and I am using vanilla HTML for the front-end.

**index.js**

```js
const express    = require('express'),
      bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
      serverless = require('serverless-http'),
      app        = express(),
      nav        = require('./routes/nav'), // the router 
      PORT       = process.env.PORT || 8080;

/* Settings */

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static('./public'));

/* APIS */
app.use('/.netlify/functions/api', nav); //Navigation API

module.exports = app;
module.exports.handler = serverless(app);

if(process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"){
  app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is runing on PORT: ${PORT} ENV: ${process.env.NODE_ENV}`);
  });
}
```

**nav.js**

```js
const express    = require('express');

const router     = express.Router();
const PATH       = "../../public/";

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render(`${PATH}index.html`)
});

router.get('/graph', (req, res) => {
  res.render(`${PATH}pages/graph.html`)
})


module.exports = router;
```

every time I try to route using the  tag it tells me "Can not get /graph"

my HTML nav

```html
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/">Home</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item mr-auto"><a class="nav-link" href="/graph">Graph Algorithims</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/sort">Sorting Algorithims</a></li>
</ul>
```

I thought the problem might be on the local server and I tried deploying to netlify to see if it works there and the same problem occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading your code, I can't seem to see where you "connect" the router.js file into your index.js.

To fix this, add the following in index.js:

```js
const router = require('path/to/router.js');
app.use(router);
```

Comment: You've registered the nav-file to the API-point `'/.netlify/functions/api'`, which makes it so that you'll have to go to `localhost:PORT/.netlify/functions/api/graph` to see your API. Does that work? I don't know what netlify has to do with this, but I would simply connect nav to `'/'` if I were you, as there are no other routes here.